# Where should Full stack JS beginner start?

Tags: javascript

So I won't say I'm a complete beginner, as I know the very basics and have a CS degree(that I'm very rusty at) but I have gone back through and refreshed myself with the CS50 Harvard course.

The last project is to build something, and I've gotten more into learning JS for unit testing at work and while we mostly use rails...I'm interested in learning the new emergent stuff.

I've heard the 70/30 rule applies to full stack devs, and I can't imagine if ever be good with front end stuff so I'd imagine that would be my "30". However with ES6 out and all these new conventions and frameworks I'm a bit lost where I should start?

There is a highly rated JS and Jquery book on Amazon I've been eyeing, but it's quite old. And I wonder about backend frameworks too.

My ideal learning "stack" would be node/react and mongo (with express for node) but it seems like a bad idea to learn them all at once. If I'm interested in backend should I just stick with learning node/express first?

Do I need to worry about ES6 as a beginner? I guess I'm just stuck where to start and in general which path I should take. I've done some dabbling in express but it seems like getting at least decent with JS and Jquery makes sense first?

Thanks

Comment: Wrong site to ask this question. Ask this on Quora instead or just google this question and find some already posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I think StackOverflow is not the right place to ask about your question and this will be soon removed or closed and tagged as "too vague", but I'm here to help and share what I know, so I'll answer anyway:

So you:

- Know the very basics of JS
- Have a CS degree
- Are interested in back-end development

Well, you're years ahead of other people starting with JS. You know something and you want to specialize in a given technology. That's great.

You can start with Node.js since you want to do back-end development, and your CS background could help you with that. Using Node.js will give you the environment you need and you can make your experiments with JavaScript there. Node.js is just a collection of JavaScript APIs for server-side programming, so learning it will also make you a better JS developer since you'll learn both together.

Do you need to worry about ES6? Well, don't think about ES6 as something different than JS. If you learn it by up-to-date JS books you'll learn it as well.

I would avoid thinking about your "stack" right now. Learn Node.js and JS by the way and you'll have a strong foundation to learn anything else you want.

Comment: Fair enough ha, problem with ES6 is that im not sure any "beginner-ish" books are up to date and include ES6.

Thanks for your help though.

Comment: No problem. Yes, you can ignore it for now and once you're comfortable writing ES5 you can search for ES6-specific guidance. I'd recommend you the "You Don't Know JS" series for JavaScript (which covers ES6 partially) for getting started, and any book by Axel Rauschmayer for ES6 specifically -- both free and available online. Good luck ;)